# Equal alignment of columns with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

I had a file with contents as below, with three columns which needed to be formatted/aligned:

```
ABCD  XYZAB 1234
PQRSTUV   STU  9113
LMN        OPRQM   8966
```

I came up with the following shell script:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3;
do printf "%s%-80s%-80s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3";
done <spaced-define.txt > tabbed-define.txt
```

and managed to get them aligned like this, with spaces in between:

```
ABCD     <SPACES>  XYZAB  <SPACES>  1234
PQRSTUV  <SPACES>  STU    <SPACES>  9113
LMN      <SPACES>  OPRQM  <SPACES>  8966
```

What I am unable to figure out is how to achieve the same alignment using tabs instead of spaces ?

```
ABCD    <TABS>  XYZAB  <TABS>  1234
PQRSTUV <TABS>  STU    <TABS>  9113
LMN     <TABS>  OPRQM  <TABS>  8966
```

Comment: With `\t` you can accomplish that.

Comment: I tried that, but because each column entry can be of variable length, the columns still remain unaligned...

Comment: How many tabs between the columns you want? Exactly one, or as many as needed to align?

Comment: Hai, I would need as many Tabs as needed to align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pipe your output to `col` it will reduce sequences of spaces to TABs when appropriate.

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3;
do printf "%-20s%-80s%-80s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3";
done <spaced-define.txt | col > tabbed-define.txt
```

Comment: This finally helped me a bit.. I realized since my Tabs were a multiple of 8 spaces, I added format specifiers, like so: do printf "%-8s%-56s%s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3";